# TypeScript compiler error: Expected ';' or ']'

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, web-essentials

This is a node project in VS 2013 with TypeScript tools and Web Essential installed (but no Resharper). I'm in process converting my javascript to typescript, and it seems to go well. However, I got a lot of errors in the Error List like

```
Error   1   Expected ';'    C:\Azure\public\js\prototypes.ts    6   11  
Error   2   Expected ',' or ']' C:\Azure\public\js\prototypes.ts    7   13  
Error   3   Expected ';'    C:\Azure\public\js\prototypes.ts    7   22  
Error   4   Expected ','    C:\Azure\public\js\prototypes.ts    13  30  
Error   5   Expected '{'    C:\Azure\public\js\prototypes.ts    13  40  
Error   6   Expected ';'    C:\Azure\public\js\prototypes.ts    13  49
```

Here is the first few lines of prototypes.js:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/moment/moment.d.ts" />
'use strict';
//-------------------------------------------------
// Math
//-------------------------------------------------
interface Math {
    lg(value: number): number;
    roundUp(value: number, digits: number): number;
    roundDown(value: number, digits: number): number;
}

if (!Math.lg) {
    Math.lg = function (value: number) : number {
        return Math.log(value) / Math.LN10;
    };
}
if (!Math.roundUp) {
    Math.roundUp = function (value, digits) {
        var factor = Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.lg(Math.abs(value))) - digits || 0);
        return Math.ceil(value / factor) * factor;
    };
}
if (!Math.roundDown) {
    Math.roundDown = function (value, digits) {
        var factor = Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.lg(Math.abs(value))) - digits || 1);
        return Math.floor(value / factor) * factor;
    };
}
```

Strange thing is that, even with those errors in the Error list, build succeeded and the app seems to be running fine. I also tried to uninstall WebEssential and TypeScript tools and then reinstall them, but no difference.

What is it complaining about?

UPDATE:

When I saw 1.5Beta, I immediately installed it. To my disappointment, I got more errors. Then, I decided to rollback to 1.4. But even worse...now when I open the same project it complains

> Your project file uses a different version of the TypeScript
>   compiler and tools than is currently installed on this machine.  No
>   compiler was found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\TypeScript\1.4\1.4\tsc.exe.  You may be able to fix this problem
>   by changing the `<TypeScriptToolsVersion>` element in your project
>   file.

I don't know why the path has an extra \1.4 now. Also, I can't find `<TypeScriptToolsVersion>` element in my project file. I searched everywhere (including registry), and couldn't find anywhere having a path like \1.4\1.4. It's becoming my TypeScript nightmare now.

Comment: Make sure you installed latest version of TypeScript for Visual Studio, there is already [1.5beta](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/107f89a0-a542-4264-b0a9-eb91037cf7af). But you need at least [version 1.4](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2d42d8dc-e085-45eb-a30b-3f7d50d55304)

Answer (score -1):

> even with those errors in the Error list, build succeeded and the app seems to be running fine.

TypeScript will not block a `.js` emit/build in the presence of type errors. This is to make it easier for you to migrate js code to ts.

That said, the code you posted also works fine:

[image: tested in atom typescript]

Comment: Good, how to get rid of those errors? It's kind of annoying.

Comment: Update your visual studio or use a different editor (https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript). There is no TypeScript error here (at least for current version of typescript)

Comment: Oh well...is this Visual Studio's problem, or TypeScript Tools problem or Web Essentials problem?

Comment: Yes. One of those three. Not a TypeScript problem